# how to handle xml UI for diffrent-2 screen resolution android

Tags: android

hi i have made UI in xml for displaying in view it is looking good in 480*800 resolution size screen but for small size 320*480 or medium screen the UI looking distorted means Buttons are not in its real position.i save all the images in ldpi,hdpi and mdpi folder and also give permission for screen support

below is my xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/mainmenuimage" 
 >

<Button android:layout_marginTop="230dip" 
android:text="currentloc" 
android:focusable="true"
android:background="@drawable/mainmenubtn" 
android:id="@+id/btn" android:layout_height="50dip"
 android:layout_width="110dip" 
 android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"/>


<Button 

     android:text="Filter"
     android:id="@+id/filter" 
     android:layout_height="50dip"
     android:layout_width="110dip"
     android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
     android:layout_marginTop="6dip" 
     android:background="@drawable/mainmenubtn"/>

 <Button 
     android:text="keyword search"
     android:id="@+id/keysearch" 
     android:layout_height="50dip"
     android:layout_width="110dip"
     android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
     android:layout_marginTop="6dip" 
     android:background="@drawable/mainmenubtn"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and manifest is:

```
        <supports-screens
             android:anyDensity = "false"
              android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true" 
              android:largeScreens="true" 


            />
```

so how to handle layout for diffrent screen ,i have read alreday all tuts in android developer side....but not  got  any...pls help thanks

Comment: i save all the images in ldpi,hdpi and mdpi folder. Means you save the same images in different directories. right?

Comment: User37, no it's not. It's the same images, but at different scales. So technically, they're not the same images at all. See my much-much longer answer below, which explains everything.

Answer (score 1):

This article descripes what to do:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

> For example, the following is a list of resource directories in an
> application that provides different layout designs for different
> screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and
> extra high density screens.
>
> res/**layout**/my_layout.xml         // layout for normal screen size
>
> res/**layout-small**/my_layout.xml  // layout for small
>
> res/**layout-large**/my_layout.xml       // layout for large
>
> res/**layout-xlarge**/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra
>
> res/**layout-xlarge-land**/my_layout.xml // layout for
> extra large in landscape orientation
>
> res/**drawable-mdpi**/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
>
> res/**drawable-hdpi**/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
>
> res/**drawable-xhdpi**/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density

Comment: hi copa i already read this answer after i post my qus..i not understood in this ..what u do for diffrent-2 resolution screen ?pls tell me in ur style

Comment: means i make diffrent-2 xml layout for each screen size?

Comment: Android sperates the different resolutions into groups. Groups are e.g.: small, large, xlarge, xlarge-land and so on. Android itself decidse which layout it will use. If you want a layout for smartphones, store it in the layout folder, and if you want one for a tablet store it in the xlarge folder. Same will work for your images. So you dont make layouts for each screen size, but for each group. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the hdpi version of your button should be 1.5 times bigger than the mdpi (baseline) version.

[image: illustration of different screen sizes for the same image at different densities]

In other words, if the height of your background mainmenubtn image is 50 px in mdpi, the hdpi version needs to be 75 px.

> res/drawable-mdpi/mainmenubtn.png
>
> res/drawable-hdpi/mainmenubtn.png

If you're on Windows, just right-click on each of those two image files in Explorer and select properties to take a look at their dimensions.

Also, 50 pixels is a bad choice for a height in Android. Stick to the standard heights as much as you can. There are good reasons those dimensions were chosen in the first place. Take a look at the [following](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#icon-sets) dimensions for standard icons (I know your buttons are not square, they're rectangle, but bear with me for a moment).

You don't have to turn your button into a square, definitely not, but if you're trying to use a size like 50 px and 75 px for a particular height, you might as well use 48 px and 72 px instead (for both the mdpi and hdpi versions respectively).

And if you're trying to use 110 px and 165 pixels for width (again, for mdpi and hdpi respectively), you should pick instead 104 px and 158 px (or something like that). In other words, you should try to maintain the original aspect ratio of the rectangle you had in mind, but also ensure that the resulting dimensions are divisible by 4.

Notice that all the screen sizes of any phone and almost all the standard icon dimensions are divisible by 4 as well (except for some the smallest icons where pixels are at a premium). That's not a coincidence. This is because dimensions are generally easier to scale and operate on when they're divisible by 4. Also note that the ldpi version is 3/4 the size of the baseline mdpi version, so that's one more reason for you to make sure that the baseline mdpi dimensions are at least divisible by 4 (even if you chose not to make the ldpi version itself divisible by 4).

And by the way, do not mess with making different layout files until you've gotten this density problem taken care of. If you're lucky, your problem may just be different densities and your application make look fine with just one normal layout file for all the different screen sizes.

And also on a different note, know that small screen sizes are only [3.4%](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html) of the Android handset Market as of September 2, 2011, and that proportion is likely to decrease over time, so keep that in mind in case you're trying to spend too much time making the layout look just right on a small-sized emulated screen.